# Tree : Find node whose common path is shortest in relation to other nodes

Tags: algorithm

```
A
|
'-- B
    |
    '-- C
    |   |
    |   '-- X1
    |
    '-- D
        |
        '-- E
        |   |
        |   '-- F
        |       |
        |       '-- X2
        |
        '-- X3
```

Given a tree and multiple paths to nodes within that tree, how can I design an algorithm that returns the node within the tree with the least common path with the other nodes.

For example:

We have the following paths to x :

1. `A -> B -> C -> x1`
2. `A -> B -> D -> E -> F -> x2`
3. `A -> B -> D -> x3`

We can see that `x2` and `x3` share a common path : `A -> B -> D` that is longer than the paths shared by `x1` and `x2` (`A -> B`) or the path shared by `x1` and `x3` (`A -> B`).

My goal is to algorithmically find `x1`.

Comment: What is the length of the "common path" of "A-B-C-D-E-F-G" and "H-B-C-I-J-E-F"? 0, 2 or 4? I.e., does the common path has to start with the first node in the path, and can it be interrupted?

Comment: Hi tobias_k, the common path has to start with the first node in the path.

Comment: @tobias_k it is a tree, so that case will not happen

Comment: Did you try lowest common ancestor algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observation:** Go from the root down to each leaf, the common path will be from the root to their lowest common ancestor nodes. In this example, lowest common ancestor are node B and node D. So, the result of this problem will always be in the path from root to the **closest lowest common ancestor**.

Also notice that from one lowest common ancestor node go down one level, we will always have a path not contains any other lowest common ancestor.

So I will propose a solution, which require two passes in the tree.

For each node in the tree, we recorded an additional information, integer `count`, which will tell at this node, it contains how many X object in its leaves (which is X1, X2 , X3 in the example).

```
class Node {
   int count = 0;
   Node []children;
}
```

So, by a single pass, we can update all the `count` information.

```
public int getCount(Node node){
    if(children is empty){
       if(this node contains object in the list)
          return 1;
       return 0;
    }else{
       for(Node child in children){
           node.count += getCount(child);
       }
    }
    return node.count;
}
```

In the second pass, from the root down to each leaf, the result of the question is in the node that has `count == 1` and nearest to the root. The `nearest to the root` is actually the level of the node in the tree.

So, in the example, we have the count for each node is :

A : 3 (level 0)

B : 3 (level 1)

C : 1 (level 2) contains result, as nearest to the root

D : 2 (level 2)

E : 1 (level 3)

F : 1 (level 4)

So, in the end, **time complexity is O(N)** with N is number of node.

**Note**: As NiklasB's mention, this whole process can be done in one single pass.

Just by modifying the `getCount` method to include the distance to the root , as well as two global variables, `min` keep the smallest distance of the node that has count is 1, the other one hold the object result.

```
int min = 100000;
Object result;

public int getCount(Node node, int distance){
    if(children is empty){
       if(this node contains object in the list)
          if(distance < min){ 
             min = distance;
             result = //X 
          }
          return 1;
       return 0;
    }else{
       for(Node child in children){
           node.count += getCount(child , distance + 1);
       }
    }
    if(node.count == 1 && distance < min){
       min = distance,
       result = //X
    }
    return node.count;
}
```

Comment: you can do both in a single pass as well

Answer (score 1):

We can observe that the common path's length is the depth of the first common ancestor. So we can start by determining the depth of relevant nodes.

We introduce labels for each node of the form:

```
grandchildren - a subset of X of direct or indirect children of the node that are relevant
depth - the node's depth
```

And we introduce additional labels for each x:

```
commonAncestorDepth - the depth of the nearest common ancestor
```

So we start at some x:

```
mark the root with grandchildren = {}, depth = 0

for each x in X
    n := x
    inverseDepth = -1
    //pass from node to first marked node 
    while n is not marked
        n.depth = inverseDepth
        inverseDepth -= 1
        add x to n.grandchildren
        n = n.parent
    end while
    //second pass to update depths
    xDepth = n.depth - inverseDepth
    while n.depth < 0
        n.depth = xDepth + inverseDepth
        n = n.parent
    end while
    x.commonAncestorDepth = n.Depth
    //update the common ancestor of paths we might have crossed        
    for each n' in n.grandchildren      
        if n'.commonAncestorDepth < n.Depth
            n'.commonAncestorDepth = n.depth
    next
next
```

Now we just need to find the element in X with minimum `commonAncestorDepth`. You might organize them in a priority queue or similar structure to get this result fast.

This algorithm is efficient if you have a big tree and only few elements in X. The worst-case complexity is **O(tree depth * |X|)**, for a perfect tree, this is O(log N * |X|) where N is the number of nodes.